# How to make Hbase resilient to name node failures in Hadoop 2

Tags: hadoop, hbase, high-availability

there is [solution for HA hadoop + hbase stack](http://hortonworks.com/blog/full-stack-ha-in-hadoop-1-hbases-resilience-to-namenode-failover/)  for hadoop 1, but i can't find any mentions on such solution for hadoop 2.

It has [name node avaliability](http://hortonworks.com/blog/namenode-high-availability-in-hdp-2-0/) but you still need to set hostname in hadoop setup, so if master name node goes down hbase remains blinded.

What solutions can you suggest for making hbase resilient to name node failures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure name service and use name service instead of specifying specific IP.
For example here "mycluster" is name service name.

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.nameservices</name>
  <value>mycluster</value>
</property>
```

And then configure for HA

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.ha.namenodes.mycluster</name>
  <value>nn1,nn2</value>
</property>
```

In hbase-site.xml also you can use "mycluster" name service to refer the cluster.

For more details, Please refer [here](http://www.cloudera.com/content/www/en-us/documentation/archive/cdh/4-x/4-7-1/CDH4-High-Availability-Guide/cdh4hag_topic_2_3.html)

Comment: Yes, thanks, we managed it yesterday. Besides that, we can't make it work without copying hdfs-site.xml and core-site.xml to you /hbase/conf dir according to http://www.cloudera.com/content/www/en-us/documentation/archive/cdh/4-x/4-7-1/CDH4-High-Availability-Guide/cdh4hag_topic_2_6.html.